# Android AsyncTask Logging fails

Tags: android, networking, background, android-asynctask, networkonmainthread

I had the following code, which was being called in a class which was registered to receive periodic (1 per second) broadcasts:

```
public void onReceive(Context c, Intent i) {
    Log.d("NET", "Polling server...");
    try {
        Request.getChanges();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.w("NET", "Error polling server: " + e.toString());
    }
}
```

However, since this code was being fired off as a BroadcastReceiver, and thus getting run in the UI thread, I was getting:

```
Error polling server: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

So I decided to try it in an AsyncTask instead:

```
public void onReceive(Context c, Intent i) {
    class Task extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            Log.d("NET", "Polling server...");
            try {
                Request.getChanges();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.w("NET", "Error polling server: " + e.toString());
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
    new Task().execute();
}
```

However, when I do this, I get no output whatsoever. Any idea what the issue is here? Thanks!

Comment: Why you didn't wrap it simply with a Thread(...)?

Comment: As I understand it, AsyncTask is basically a wrapper around spawning a new thread that makes the process a little easier.

Comment: Do you have any other AsyncTask besides this one in your app?

Comment: Yeah I do. Should that matter?

Comment: I wonder if it has to do with the `Void`s. I think I came up on a problem similar to this and just passed an empty `String` to avoid it.

Comment: Oh huh. I'll give it a try.

Comment: See my answer below, hope it helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you hit the same wall than me a few weeks ago. I already had one `AsyncTask` running perfectly, I copied the same structure for another one, tried to start it - no result. I was going already mad with it, when I reached [this](http://www.jayway.com/2012/11/28/is-androids-asynctask-executing-tasks-serially-or-concurrently/).

Resuming, all you have to do is:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR1)
  new Task().execute();
else
  new Task().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
```